# How to make a HTML5 canvas paint application responsive using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

What are corrections in the code to make it responsive and to make circle and rectangle appear on screen where ever user clicks.

```
<script>
   function mouseDown(e) {
     var a= e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
     var b= e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
   }

   function c1()
   {
    ctx.arc(currX,currY,41,0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
   }
   function r1(e)
   {
    var a= e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var b= e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    ctx.rect(a,b,Math.abs(prevX - currX), Math.abs(prevY - currY)); 
    ctx.stroke();
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this canvas responsive using the window's width and height.

I have tried some code below when can help.

```
<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas_id'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 function init(){
   canvas.height = window.innerHeight(); //innerHeight is the viewable screen
   canvas.width = window.innerWidth();
 }

init(); //call this function when the page loads maybe in the body tag
</script>
```

The bit about making circles and rectangles I am not sure what you are asking for.